# JSF action from onChange

Tags: jsf, input, onchange

I'm trying to set up a data table with JSF that has boxes for row total that will sum the row total onChange of any box in the row. the row looks like:

```html
<tr id="input_row_1">
<td id="mondayInput1">
    <h:inputText id="monday1" size="4" value="#{timesheet.monday1}" required="false" />
    <!-- <input name="monday1" class="smallInput" type="number" size="2" maxlength="4" min="0"/> -->
</td>
<td id="tuesdayInput1">
    <h:inputText id="tuesday1" size="4" value="#{timesheet.tuesday1}" required="false" />
    <!--<input name="tuesday1" class="smallInput" type="number" size="2" maxlength="4" min="0"/> -->
</td>
<td id="wednesdayInput1">
    <h:inputText id="wednesday1" size="4" value="#{timesheet.wednesday1}" required="false" />
    <!--<input name="wednesday1" class="smallInput" type="number" size="2" maxlength="4" min="0"/> -->
</td>
<td id="thursdayInput1">
    <h:inputText id="thursday1" size="4" value="#{timesheet.thursday1}" required="false" />
    <!--<input name="thursday1" class="smallInput" type="number" size="2" maxlength="4" min="0"/> -->
</td>
<td id="fridayInput1">
    <h:inputText id="friday1" size="4" value="#{timesheet.friday1}" required="false" />
    <!--<input name="friday1" class="smallInput" type="number" size="2" maxlength="4" min="0"/> -->
</td>
<td id="saturdayInput1">
    <h:inputText id="saturday1" size="4" value="#{timesheet.saturday1}" required="false" />
    <!--<input name="saturday1" class="smallInput" type="number" size="2" maxlength="4" min="0"/> -->
</td>
<td id="sundayInput1">
    <h:inputText id="sunday1" size="4" value="#{timesheet.sunday1}" required="false" />
    <!--<input name="sunday1" class="smallInput" type="number" size="2" maxlength="4" min="0"/> -->
</td>
<td>
    <h:inputText id="total1" size="4" value="#{timesheet.total1}" required="false" />
    <!-- <input name="total1" id="total1" type="text" size="5" readonly="readonly" /> -->
</td>
```

so I first tried to add `onChange="#{timesheet.setTotal1}"` to the day entries but the onChange event calls javascript, not java / JSF code. Can someone help get the total to update?

EDIT: 
I have accepted BalusC's answer but needed to also include the `event` attribute to the `<f:ajax>` tag to get it to work, like so

```
<h:inputText id="friday1" size="4" value="#{timesheet.friday1}" maxlength="4" required="false" >
    <f:ajax event="change" render="total1" listener="#{timesheet.updateTotal1}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, the `onchange` attribute is just treated as a plain text HTML attribute which should represent a JavaScript `onchange` handler function. This is not different from in "plain vanilla" HTML. Any EL expressions in that attribute will just be treated as value expressions. See also the [tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html).

Based on your question history, you're using JSF 2.x (please explicitly mention the exact JSF impl/version in future questions as many things are done differently in JSF 2.x as compared to JSF 1.x). So, just using the new JSF 2.0 `<f:ajax>` tag should do it.

```
<h:inputText ...>
    <f:ajax listener="#{timesheet.changeTotal1}" render="idOfTotalComponent" />
</h:inputText>

...

<h:outputText id="idOfTotalComponent" value="#{timesheet.total1}" />
```

with

```
public void changeTotal1(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    total1 = ...;
}
```

Comment: I did this, and am now getting: "javax.servlet.ServletException: Property 'updateTotal1' not found on type com.timesheet.Timesheet" as if updateTotal1 is a property rather than an method / action

Comment: On the `<f:ajax listener>`, you mean? Apparently the XML namespace of the `f:` taglib hasn't been declared at all. The whole `<f:xxx>` tag would then indeed be treated as "plain text" (read: any EL is then treated as a value expression).

Comment: But it has been declared, I just didn't include all of the html code

Comment: Sorry, the cause of this problem is not visible in the code/information provided so far. An SSCCE would be helpful.